# How can I cast propertiesconfiguration class from apache to hashmap?

Tags: java, apache, properties, configuration

Propertiesconfiguration class from: https://commons.apache.org/

These are the libraries I am using:

```
import org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.PropertiesConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.reloading.FileChangedReloadingStrategy;
```

Code:

```
PropertiesConfiguration configWatchdog;


            try {
              configWatchdog = new PropertiesConfiguration(configName);
              // FileChangedReloadingStrategy reload = new FileChangedReloadingStrategy();
              configWatchdog.setReloadingStrategy(new FileChangedReloadingStrategy());
              // String a= configWatchdog.getString("controller.tresholdValue");
              componentConfiguration = (Map<String, Object>) configWatchdog;

              // componentConfiguration.put("controller.tresholdValue",
              // configWatchdog.getString("controller.tresholdValue"));

            } catch (ConfigurationException exception) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              exception.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I like to watch configuration changes on runtime and use the changes to check values. Someone got an idea how I can get the values?